# Massive PHP array vs MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm debating in my head whether I should use a massive, multidimensional array or a database in MySQL. I'm developing for a client whose business has many products. In this multidimensional array I would include the product title, description, image link and categories for each individual product.

My client has perhaps 1000+ products. I've researched other similar questions and many of them say that an array is perhaps faster, however none of them are dealing with an array of this scale.

I personally would much rather use an array, because my knowledge with MySQL is extremely limited, but if it means sacrificing a significant amount of speed then I would rather use the database. Which would you consider a more appropriate option for my case?

Comment: It's your opportunity to learn MySQL, use it! (yes it's better than a big array)

Comment: 1000 items in an array is pretty much nothing, unless you're working with an extremely memory-constricted system.

Comment: Use a database! All database engines have already implemented common methods (e.g. 'JOIN') and optimizations. You would need to write these in PHP yourself if you plan to use arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just in my honest opinion I would go with a Database. Here is my reasoning.

With a database you will get a small performance loss as connection times, communication, and query times. However, the gain will come from a few aspects.

1. Far better and easier manipulation.
2. Stability, Security, and cloud capabilities.
3. Because dealing with a huge array will become a huge pain in the rear.

Also, viewing the data will be much easier with a database to the naked eye.

Comment: 4. as the array grows, looking up data via a database index will be quicker than looping through a large array.

Comment: Thank you for all of your thoughts on this. I have decided to go with a MySQL DB. It just seems much easier to maintain in the long run, since we will probably be continuously adding more products over time. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you have any questions about interacting with MYSQL through php feel free to ask. I could also provide some working samples. I am new to the site (answering questions, been using the site for a while) and I'm not sure if you can message on here, if not email me jjonesdesign@gmail.com

Answer (score 9):

The other answers are right - but for the wrong reasons.

Holding the data in a PHP array it will be much faster to fetch than from a database - even if the dataset is cached in memory. The issue is that in normal PHP architectures each request is handled by a seperate process. Hence each request which needs access to the data will have to load the entire dataset into memory. This takes time. The point at which it becomes more expensive to perform this operation rather than retrieving items from a database depends on a lot of different factors - but as a rough rule of thumb it's in the region of 100 records. There are applications where this model makes sense - but they rely on very small data volumes and a controlled process of changing / managing the data.

Your next problem is that you'll probably want to record some transactions against the stock - that means changing the data - and that means serializing access to ensure that 2 separate transactions don't happen at the same time. It is impossible to implement this in PHP (without a dedicated daemon to adjudicate) while not having deadlocks.

If you are charging someone for implementing the code, then it should be blindingly obvious that trying to implement this in memory is a very, very bad idea.

Comment: I'm considering using a database instead of multidimensional arrays of objects, just to be able to use database actions, in my game. So when an android application runs, each database action has to interact with physical memory on the device instead of the RAM memory given to the application? It seems a database would slow a game way down when you're doing hundreds of interactions a second.

Comment: Any sources/prove to back this claim? I have an array that will never change and always will be queried in its entirity. However, the array has more than 10,000 elements. The file where I keep the array is about 2MB in size. I guess there is also a cost at some point where PHP has to load the entire file into memory? Would there be any benefits loading 10,000 records from DB into the array instead?

I know that in essence mysql is also using the file system, but would there be any reason to think that mysql does this in a more performant manner?

Comment: measure it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The code using an array will be simpler, and won't have the complication of a MySQL database. If that **data is static**, and there are no other uses or users of that data, then the array is fine.

On the other hand, if that data needs to change, or that data would be useful for some other business functions, then a MySQL database would be the way to go.

Comment: You realize that everytime the page loads, all the "records" would have to be evaluated and brought to the RAM before you could send the html to the browser, right?

Comment: You realize that everytime the page loads, the PHP code is brought into RAM and interpreted, right? You realize that if he'd use a MySQL database, then everytime the page is loaded it's got to load the MySQL driver, and establish a connection to the database, queries have to be sent to the database, and resultsets have to be retrieved into RAM (and across the network, if the database is not on the same machine) before HTML is sent to the browser, right? Using MySQL will likely increase the amount of RAM required, and increase the number of instructions that will be executed; it's not free.

Comment: Telling people to not use a database is a nice way to create maintenance nightmares. There are no performance benefits to not using a database.  Certainly not when the guy has 1000+ products.  Now, if he only had 2, maybe. But even then, shouldn't he expect the company to grow its catalog and thus use a database? Common sense.  And making an SQL query to get one item will NOT equal the amount of RAM used for storing 1000+ objects.

Answer (score 2):

Let's talk about memory consumption a bit.

One single array element in PHP consumes 144 bytes of data, not counting any string text (that goes extra).

An array with 1000 elements then uses 144.000 bytes plus text strings - that does not really seem a lot.

But you cannot create a useful data structure just with one value, so your 1000 elements would probably be an array with sub elements. Let's assume just 10 elements per array. That would be 1440 bytes for each element's array, multiplied with 1000 elements. Not we are getting close to 1.440.000 bytes. Still like "nothing", but what about text? What about an even more complex sub structure. How big will it be in the end?

And additionally, that array has to be in memory for EVERY concurrent request. And has to be loaded somehow. Unserializing an array does take some considerable amount of CPU power.

In the end: Use a database! There is no benefit pushing all data in memory.