# Deny checkout only if both Unique Firstname and Unique Address_1 fields are in blacklist in PHP

Tags: php

In `checkout.php`  I need to block blacklisted users and deny checkout. The code below I added in PHP script works but needed fine tuning as it is having 2 issues that needed solution:

The topic is different from  "Deny checkout if Street Address is on blacklist". Because, I need 2 conditions in each blacklist must be matched before denying checkout.

```
//Block if First name is in blacklist

$blacklistedfirstname = array("raj", "ken" ,"ber" ); 

foreach ($blacklistedfirstname  as $blacklist_firstname) {
    if (stripos($post['firstname'], $blacklist_firstname) !== false) {
        $error[$type . '_firstname'] = "Oops ! Something went wrong. Contact the administrator";
    }
}

// Block if address_1 in blacklist

$blacklistedaddress = array("1, Vee Street", "2,BB Street",  "street2","street3");

foreach ($blacklistedaddress  as $blacklist_address) {
    if (stripos($post['address'], $blacklist_address) !== false) {
        $error[$type . '_address_1'] = "Oops ! Something went wrong. Contact the administrator";
    }
}
```

Two issues are:
Though it works individually and block if entered values are in blacklist, I face two issues.

Issue 1. The first name condition blocks all names starting with "Raj" as it is in blacklist. for ex. if  "Raju" is entered, though the name is different from what is in blacklist, it still blocks. It must block only if "Raj" is entered exactly including lower case.

Issue 2. The `address_1` field has values that are in blacklisted address. But I needed to block only if Firstname and `address_1` values are both in blacklist. This is because, First name can be same for many people. Also street address can be same for some people. Genuine users must not be blocked. So, this unique combination of First name and address_1 blacklist check will ensure that, the particular user alone is blocked. Also instead of throwing errors independently for these 2 fields, a common error can be added when both Firstname and address_1 field values are in blacklist.

Comment: 1 & 2: Then stop using strpos and compare the complete text rather than bits of it

Comment: 1 & 2: Set a flag if you find data in the blacklist. Test both flags after the loops to see if both are set. _simples_

Comment: @ RiggsFolly
Thank you. If possible can you please post example code of your method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not standard. You should learn more to use DB and better ways!

But to answer your question:

```php
$blacklistedfirstname = ["raj", "ken" ,"ber"]; 
$blacklistedaddress = ["1, Vee Street", "2,BB Street",  "street2","street3"];

$is_f_bl = in_array($post['firstname'], $blacklistedfirstname);
$is_a_bl = in_array($post['address'], $blacklistedaddress);

if($is_f_bl && $is_a_bl){
  $error = "Oops ! Something went wrong. Contact the administrator";
}
```

There is no need to do a loop through arrays!

Just use `in_array()` function which doe's the job of searching in array!
this function returns a `boolean` value: `true` if needle is found otherwise `false`.More [docs here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

If both fields found in blacklist it will show error!

Comment: @ Alijvhr IT WORKS good. Thank you. But can you please post example code for me on how to  use DB, with this same php code parameters, as you said "This question is not standard. You should learn more to use DB and better ways!".

Comment: @VSR `DB` means `Database`. You can start using [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) and progress. You can continue every page using next button!

Comment: @ Alijvhr  I know DB means database. I was asking, how to implement it for the present code. Thank you. I will read it in W3schools.

Comment: By using DB for blacklist, please tell me, what is the difference if I am using it in fixed array as blacklist in php code above. Any special advantage using DB for the list. For validation anyways php must be used.

Comment: @ Alijvhr. Also why some people wanted to blacklist w3schools as in the Link ?        https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/94490/instruct-google-search-to-blacklist-w3schools-com-from-search-results

Comment: @VSR w3schools is sometimes a primitive website with misleading info if you are getting pro! But it's good for start. Db is more flexible and standard way! You should  save your address and names in db! For manage large data and store and retrieve it  db is the only answer. No one hard code info! [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18706762/21017967)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying about w3schools and the link about DB l and array debate.

Comment: @ Alijvhr  I switched from ordinary php array to Database. I added a table called "blacklist" and email and other required column . II  uses Database query and fetched rows and validated successfully. You motivated me to use DB in the right direction.

Comment: if($is_f_bl && $is_a_bl){
  $error = "Oops ! ...";
}                                                                                                                                               the above code works good. But, what happens is that it blocks if it matches name in one row and street address in another row, it blocks as blacklisted.. It should block only if it matches in a particular row all together. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: @VSR add your SQLtables to your question or open another question and describe your question specifically, and I will answer you then! this is irrelevant.

Comment: I will post new question with tables and DB query I used. If I edit my question adding tables throws error.

Comment: I have posted the question with database tables and php coded used:                     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76323380/implement-blacklist-with-values-in-two-columns-in-same-row                                                                                                              Please help. Thank you